# Qt Application crash when setting QTimer interval

Tags: android, c++, qt, timer

This is my first question, the reason i signed up to the site. I'm developing a game using Qt 5.9 and I use QTimer to spawn enemies on the screen. Everytime the timer's timeout function is called, an enemy is spawned. 
What i try to do is if a player kills let's say 10 enemies, the timer interval decreases, so the enemies will spawn more frequently, making the game a little bit more challenging. The first time the timer interval is set, the game runs perfectly, but the second time the `setInterval()` method is called, when the player kills 10 enemies, the game suddenly crashes. I tried debugging it to figure out what might cause it, and it seems that it crashes when i try to set the spawnInterval. 
I'm fairly new to coding so any advice is appreciated! Here are the relevant source files and codes from my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <game.h>

Game * game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    game = new Game();

    game->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

game.h:

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "Player.h"
#include "score.h"
#include "Health.h"

class Game: public QGraphicsView{
public:
    Game(QWidget * parent=0);
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    Player * player;
       Score * score;
       Health * health;
       void setSpawnInterval(int spawnValue);
       int getSpawnInterval();
        void setTimerInterval();
private:
       int spawnInterval = 1000;
};
#endif // GAME_H
```

game.cpp:

```
QTimer * timer1 = new QTimer();
QObject::connect(timer1,SIGNAL(timeout()),player,SLOT(spawn()));
timer1->start(getSpawnInterval());
}
void Game::setSpawnInterval(int spawnValue){

 //this is the part where it crashes
spawnInterval = spawnValue;
}

int Game::getSpawnInterval(){
    return spawnInterval;
}
```

score.h

```
#ifndef SCORE_H
#define SCORE_H

#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

class Score: public QGraphicsTextItem{
public:
    Score(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
    void increase();
    int getScore();

private:
    int score;
};
#endif // SCORE_H
```

score.cpp

```
#include "score.h"
#include <QFont>
#include "game.h"
#include <QTimer>

void Score::increase()
{
    score++;

    if(score > 3){
    Game * game;
        game->setSpawnInterval(200);}

    //Draw the text to the display
    setPlainText(QString("Score: ") + QString::number(score));

}

int Score::getScore()
{
    return score;
}
```

player.h

```
    #ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QObject>

class Player: public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     Player(QGraphicsItem * parent=0);
   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);
    int jumpPhaseNumber = 0;
    bool jumpRun = false;
public slots:
   void spawn();
   void jumpPhase();

};

#endif
```

player.cpp

```
void Player::spawn()
{
    Enemy * enemy = new Enemy();
    scene()->addItem(enemy);

}
```

Comment: game is not initialized.

Comment: You mean: " Game *game = new Game()" instead of "Game *game"? I tried it, but it creates a new window and the game starts again in that window.

Comment: @Bencsizy Is it possible for you to change time out without starting timer. like this : `//timer1->start(getSpawnInterval());`   , `timer1->setInterval(getSpawnInterval());`  I want to make sure changing time interval is not the problem.

Comment: No! I mean you are not allowed to dereference an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Tried it: if i change that line to the line you mentioned, enemies won't start to spawn. I added another line after that: "timer1->start();" and then they started to spawn, but then it crashed at score = 3 just as before.

Comment: @manni66 Could you show me through code example to how to do that?

Comment: @Bencsizy I see that class `score` using class `game` and class `game` using class `player`. Are you sure you are creating only one instance of class game ? only one instance in class `score`

Comment: @Bencsizy Very good, that's the problem. two instance of class game.if you want to change a value from multi classes use Static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are creating two instance of class `game`.

I suggest you to use static variables for accessing from multi classes.

add this class to your project:

.cpp

```
#include "settings.h"

int Settings::spawnInterval = 1000;

Settings::Settings(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

.h

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class Settings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Settings(QObject *parent = 0);

    static int spawnInterval;
};

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

now we have a static variable name `spawnInterval`, you can access it (set/get) from any classes that include settings class like this:

```
#include <settings.h>

Settings::spawnInterval = 100; // set
int value = Settings::spawnInterval; //get
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `Game * game; game->setSpawnInterval(200)` causes your program to crash: you must initialize the game pointer; to fix this, for example, you can hold a reference (pointer) of game inside the Score class, thus letting you call setSpawnInterval; I would construct Score inside Game's constructor passing `this`as a parameter; this saves you from creating a new class, as @aghilpro suggested. Actually a `struct` would be better since your information is public and accessible from other classes without the need to implement getters/setters.